# Edit response body with request and node

Tags: node.js, express

Im trying to create a small proxy server that i can edit the request and response between client and server.

This is what I've got so far:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var request = require('request');


app.use('/login', function(req, res) {

    var url = request.post({
        uri: 'http://192.168.1.53', 
        json: req.body
    });

    req.pipe(url).pipe(res);
});


app.listen(7501);
```

It works perfectly for my situation. But I need to edit the request and response. 
Namely the cookies returned and form data sent.
Any help would be great. Pretty new to Node.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up with this - took in the request with express, then created a new post request with request. and then some magic happens that returns the second response back through express to the client.

```
app.use('/login', function(req, res) {
 request.post(
    'http://192.168.1.53',
    { form: { req: 'auth',  cid: '1', em: req.body.em, pw: req.body.pw, rm: true} },
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            var cookie = response.headers['set-cookie'];
            console.log(cookie)
            console.log(body) //using body-parser

            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE');
            res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
            res.json({ success: true });
        }
    }
);

});
```